# Как правильно шифровать данные с паролем в MySQL? MD5

Tags: mysql, sql

Знаю, что в бд хранятся пароли, зашифрованные с помощью MD5. Можно ли установить эту функцию колонке таблицы( то есть при `INSERT INTO table (password) VALUES ('123')` в таблице автоматически будет записано хэшированное значение)? Если да, то как это сделать? Или при вставке данных необходимо каждый раз использовать хэш-функцию?

Comment: Заранее хэшируйте пароль, а только потом пишите его в базу любым способом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT INTO table (password) VALUES (MD5('123')) - самое оптимальное.

Автоматически можно через триггер, но ИМХО я бы сказал, что это слишком сложно для подобного случая.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `db_table_password` BEFORE INSERT ON `db`.`table`
  FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      SET NEW.password = md5(NEW.password );
   END
```

И лучше юзать SHA2, он безопасней https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2

Comment: `(MD5('123')) - самое оптимальное.` нельзя использовать в запросах сырые пароли на случай если запрос попадёт в лог. смысл как раз в том чтобы в базе никаких следов пароля не было, а только хэш

Comment: Вы правы, но я отвечал на конкретный вопрос, в котором приведен пример с открытой вставкой пароля в БД. Почему, зачем - отдельная тема, на совести автора. Я ее не хочу касаться, потому что она выходит за рамки вопроса.